# Should I mention I own a car in my visa cover letter? Should I include monthly car payments in my monthly spending?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

I want to submit my UK visa application this week.

In October I paid about 20% of the car's price and November 1st was the first car installment payment. I don't think I will include this 20% payment as every month's spending because it's a one time thing. But should I include the installments as monthly spending? I don't know how much I will spend each month because November is not over yet.

I submitted bank statements from August to October, should I also include bank statements from November until now?

Comment: Submitting 6 months’ bank statements is generally the standard practice. Is there a reason you can’t submit statements prior to August? Not doing so could be a red flag, especially if you don’t have a ‘squeaky clean’ travel history (eg a previous refusal).

Comment: I called them they said I can submit 3 months bank statements only

Comment: You can submit as many or as few statements as you like, my point is that 3 months’ worth may not be sufficient to satisfy the ECO and might lead to a refusal under V4.2(e) on the grounds that your financial standing could not be fully determined. If I were you I would wait 2 months before applying so that I could submit 6 months’ statements.

Answer (score 19):

Having a car payment (or not) is **highly unlikely** to be material to your visa application.  They're really looking for two things: Do you have a stable income that lets you afford the trip to the UK? Do you have strong ties to your home country so you leave after the trip is over? Having a partly paid car at home is mildly useful, but it's not going to make or break your visa.

The only reason you *might* want to mention the car is if the 20% down payment makes your October cash flow deeply negative.  If so, you should note that this was a one-off and the following monthly payments are affordable for you.

This epic answer goes into much more detail about this general topic: [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Comment: hardly it will make but sometimes, sometimes break? (I am not a lawyer and this is just common sense)